# Represent an arbitrarily nested JSON object in proto3

Tags: json, protocol-buffers, proto

Consider the following JSON representation of an object. Its top level field names and its nestedness are only known at runtime. Can this be represented in proto3 ?

```
{
    "xyz": [{
        "abc": "vala",
        "def": {
            "uvy": "val33",
            "cde": {
                "ghi": "val99"
            }
        },
        "ghi": "valc"
    }],
    "klm": ["val2","val3"],
    "prs": "val3"
}
```

Is a simple Struct sufficient for this?

```
message MyMessage {
   google.protobuf.Struct value = 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`Struct` docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/struct) do draw a similarity between the `Struct` and JSON. Indeed, perusing the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto) it seems relatively simple to encode your data this way.

But since you already have JSON data, why not serialize it as text and pass it that way instead?